# Capacitor storage or cordova storage

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I'm developing a PWA application with ionic v5 and I need to save some content offline to present to users.
I'm thinking to use Capacitor to publish my web application into a native app as an alternative to Cordova, but the data storage is an important point of my application.
Are capacitor storage and Cordova storage the same?

Comment: there is similar functionality available through a Capacitor plugin - https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For PWAs:** *Capacitor Storage* falls back to using `localStorage`. While *Ionic Storage* (utilizing Cordova) uses `IndexedDB`, `WebSQL`, and `localstorage`, in that order.

> Are capacitor storage and Cordova storage the same?

Briefly: **No.** Storage highly depends on the platform your app is running on. Capacitor and Cordova take on a different approach in this regard. They will automatically use the appropriate local storage system for each platform.

**How to choose storage for Native Apps:**

1. **For High Performance Storage:** Use [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage) that uses Cordova SQLite plugin. It is key-value based access but uses SQLite underneath by default. Howeever, when running in the web or as a **Progressive Web App**, Storage will attempt to use IndexedDB, WebSQL, and localstorage, in that order.
2. **For casual storage:** If you want to store data that should be persistent but does not require high level of querying, then use [Capacitor Storage](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage). It will use `UserDefaults` on iOS and `SharedPreferences` on Android.
   But, this API will fall back to using localStorage when running as a Progressive Web App.
3. **For UnImportant Data:** You can simply use **localStorage** and don't need any additional storage engine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @pankaj-sati. If I will use **localStorage**, when users clean the browser data in local devices, these data will be lost, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it will be deleted

Comment: Pwa will use browser storage so any data will be deleted whether you store it in localStorage or IndexedDB